# How do I save data using NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: uitextview, ios11, nscoding, swift4, nskeyedarchiver

I am very close to finishing my first iOS App using Swift 4 and iOS 11.

The app has a list displayed in a table view controller and a detail view with a UITextView object that is editable. My goal is for the user to be able to make edits to the content in the UITextView and save those changes using NSKeyedArchiver.

I have the list view complete and the detail view connected. You can make edits but they do not save.

I have confirmed that the entry does save to memory that persists beyond the session, but the edits do not save.

Reviews of documentation and working through multiple tutorials have not provided the insights needed. I have attached a screen shot to show the interface of the detail view and here is the code from the detail view controller where the save button triggers the Save action:

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate  {

  var season: Season?

  //MARK: Properties

  @IBOutlet weak var seasonDetail: UITextView!
  @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let selectedDetail = seasonDetail.text {
      seasonDetail.text = selectedDetail
    } else {
      print("failed to save changes.")
    }
    saveChanges()
    print("Save button clicked")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      title = season?.name
      seasonDetail.text = season?.detail
    seasonDetail.delegate=self
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    season?.detail = (seasonDetail?.text)!
  }

  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    seasonDetail.text = season?.detail
  }

  //MARK: UITextViewdDelegate

  func textViewShouldReturn(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
  }


 func saveChanges() {
    print("Saving items to: \(Season.ArchiveURL)")
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(season as Any, toFile: Season.ArchiveURL.path)

    if isSuccessfulSave {
      os_log("Season sucessfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } else {
      os_log("Failed to save season.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the code from the data model class:

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class Season: NSObject, NSCoding {

  //MARK: Properties

  var name: String
  var detail: String

  //MARK: Archiving Paths

  static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
  static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("season")

  //MARK: Types

  struct PropertyKey {
    static let name = "name"
    static let detail = "detail"
  }


  //MARK: Initialization
  init?(name: String, detail: String) {

    guard !name.isEmpty else {
      return nil
    }

    guard !detail.isEmpty else {
      return nil
    }

    // Initialize stored properties
    self.name = name
    self.detail = detail

  }

  //MARK: NSCoding

  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
    aCoder.encode(detail, forKey: PropertyKey.detail)
  }

  required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    // the name is required. If we cannnot get a name string, the initializer should fail.
    guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String
      else {
      os_log("Unable to decode the name for a Season object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
      return nil
    }

    let detail = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.detail)

    self.init(name: name, detail: detail as! String)
    }
  }
```

My goal is to understand what is missing with my code and know how to persist all the data, including the edits. I would appreciate any direction that would help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate  {
    var season: Season?
    @IBOutlet weak var seasonDetail: UITextView!
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let selectedDetail = seasonDetail.text {
            season?.detail = selectedDetail // this is the line
        } else {
            print("failed to save changes.")
        }
        saveChanges()
        print("Save button clicked")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if season == nil {
            season = Season(name: "Season Name", detail: "Season Details")
        }
        title = season?.name
        seasonDetail.text = season?.detail
        seasonDetail.delegate=self
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        season?.detail = (seasonDetail?.text)!
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
         season?.detail = seasonDetail.text
    }

    //MARK: UITextViewdDelegate
    func textViewShouldReturn(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func saveChanges() {
        print("Saving items to: \(Season.ArchiveURL)")
        let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(season as Any, toFile: Season.ArchiveURL.path)

        if isSuccessfulSave {
            os_log("Season sucessfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        } else {
            os_log("Failed to save season.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vini, how do I indicate the updated value? Thanks.

Comment: I did that by updating detail with `seasonDetail.text`

Comment: No it does not save it. Is there anything further I can provide to help shed light on the problem?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check